# wxPython - open, edit and save csv-file in wx.grid

Tags: python, user-interface, csv, wxpython, wxgrid

I would like to open a CSV file with the following structure:

```
value1;value2
value3;value4
value5;value6
```

The content of the file has to be displayed in a wx.table.
As far as I'm all done. Here is my code:

```
class FormLohnarten(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Konvertierungstabelle", size=(650,320))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        content = {}
        with open ("../../data/lohnarten.csv", "r") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
            for i in reader:
                content[i[0]] = i[1]

        self.myGrid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
        self.myGrid.CreateGrid(len(content), 2)
        self.myGrid.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGED, self.change_value)
        spalte = 0
        for i in content:
            self.myGrid.SetCellValue(spalte,0,i)
            self.myGrid.SetCellValue(spalte,1,content[i])
            spalte += 1
        print self.myGrid.GetCellValue(0,0)
        self.myGrid.AppendRows()
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.myGrid)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
```

Now I want to change the values in this table and save accordingly again in the same CSV file.
Do you have good ideas how I could implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the opposite of reading the data should do it.  IOW, extract the values from the grid, create a `cvs.writer` and use it to write the data values to the file a row at a time.  Note that `csv` doesn't handle unicode yet so as you pull the values from the grid you ought to convert them to ascii or utf-8 strings.